# Display specific div with scroll in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I've created a slider in the footer with shortcode (in a div id #oter) and I need to display none on load and display on onscroll. 
Now I have this by plugin:

```
!function(e){e(document).ready(function(){var n=0;e(window).scroll(function(){var o=e(this).scrollTop();o>n?e("#oter").fadeOut(200):e("#oter").fadeIn(200),n=o})})}(jQuery);
```

Can I change to: hidden onload and display onscroll? 
Can you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would hide this by default with CSS and then on scroll, add a new class which would then show it.

```
 $(function() {
    var footerslider = $("#oter");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 500) {
           footerslider.addClass('show');
        } else {
           footerslider.removeClass("show");
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

you are getting a console error... try updating the code to:

**please note that you will need to change the value inside the if statement so that the class gets added at the right scroll point.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var footerslider = $("#oter");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 10) {
           footerslider.addClass('show');
        } else {
           footerslider.removeClass("show");
        }
    });
});
```

and add the following css to your stylesheet:

```
#oter {
    display:none;
}

.show {
    display:block !important;
}
```

Comment: I have created a display none for #oter.

Comment: Hi @CristianRossi, sorry the #oter is still showing? cant see a display none on #oter?  Is the aim to remove the red section untill you scroll down or click the arrow to go down?

Comment: If #oter display none not see with or without a scroll. Now I delete #oter on the css. 
I would to hide the red section on load and see when the mouse scroll.

Comment: okay, i've just edited my anwser, please try that and let me know if this worked?

Comment: You need to resolve the console error for the add class to work. Update the JS in your auto-hide-header.js to the updated jquery code..

Comment: ok thanks. I've updated your code. I'm trying to resolve the console error.

Comment: okay let me know how you get on, the updated code above should have no errors, just need to ensure that you have jquery running on the page.

Comment: OK. At the moment on safari is ok.

Comment: Working for me :) The only issue that you are going to have is when you have a large browser window, since there is no scroll view, the function will never run..

I would also add another function so that on click of the arrow down, it shows as well to resolve this..

Comment: oh yes. Chrome and Firefox don't show if don't have a space for scroll :( all browser see only the background if not have a space scroll. You are right!

Comment: let me know if you need help with anything else?

Comment: I add a div with height in the end. This is a bad solution but is a solution. Thanks for help me! 
If you have a good idea for scroll I'm ready to listen :)
_js is not my language_
Thank you **very** much.

Comment: Maybe take a look at wow.js - this may be able to achieve what you are looking for?  http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

Comment: WOW have a plug-in for wordpress and I'm use it. 
Thanks for support @heady12